# Databricks Connect and External Libraries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using databricks on Azure, and part of my process include using TwoSigma's [`Flint`](https://github.com/twosigma/flint). I upload the library to the databricks libraries, and I am able to run the example code below in notebooks on the databricks workspace.

The problem arises when I try to use `databricks-connect`. While normally everything works, when trying to use external libraries, including `Flint`, the following code, running under `spark-shell --packages 'com.twosigma:flint:0.6.0'`, produces the error below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.twosigma.flint.timeseries.TimeSeriesRDD
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(("2018-08-20", 1.0), ("2018-08-20", 2.0), ("2018-08-21", 3.0)).toDF("time", "number").withColumn("time", from_utc_timestamp($"time", "UTC"))
val tsRdd = TimeSeriesRDD.fromDF(df)(isSorted=false, timeUnit=DAYS)
val results = tsRdd.groupByCycle()
results.toDF.show
```

The error is as follows:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 78.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 78.0 (TID 2164, 10.139.64.7, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType.fieldIndex(StructType.scala:302)
        at com.twosigma.flint.timeseries.TimeSeriesStore$.getInternalRowConverter(TimeSeriesStore.scala:108)
        at com.twosigma.flint.timeseries.TimeSeriesStore$$anonfun$2.apply(TimeSeriesStore.scala:53)
        at com.twosigma.flint.timeseries.TimeSeriesStore$$anonfun$2.apply(TimeSeriesStore.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$client1f520962c6$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:817)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$client1f520962c6$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:817)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$13.apply(Executor.scala:497)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1526)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Am I specifying the dependencies the wrong way?

Comment: Is the TwoSigma library installed on your local machine?

Comment: I tried loading it using either `--packages` option or with `--jar` option in the `spark-shell` command.

Comment: @tmrlvi which version of spark are you using? thus it is working perfectly fine with spark 2.+.

Comment: @MaheshGupta Which version of Databricks runtime did you use? I used 5.5, which implies spark 2.4.3, scala 2.11 and databricks-connect 5.5.1.

Comment: @tmrlvi I am using community version of 6.1 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

Comment: The version of DBR and DB Connect need to match, (i.e., 5.5 to 5.5.) .

Comment: @MaheshGupta Are you sure you used `databricks-connect`? I didn't see a way to generate user token in databricks community.

Comment: @RaphaelK My versions are the same. Both are 5.5. The micro version of the python is the newest (note that in the documentation they say to use `pip install databricks-connect==5.5.*` for version 5.5)

Answer (score -1):

To specify dependencies you'll need to include them as JAR files that get shared across the cluster.  From the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#work-with-dependencies):

> Typically your main class or Python file will have other dependency JARs and files. You can add such dependency JARs and files by calling `sparkContext.addJar("path-to-the-jar")` or `sparkContext.addPyFile("path-to-the-file")`. You can also add Egg files and zip files with the `addPyFile()` interface. Every time you run the code in your IDE, the dependency JARs and files are installed on the cluster.

Here's an example in Scala (also from the docs):

```scala
package com.example

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

case class Foo(x: String)

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      ...
      .getOrCreate();
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")

    println("Running simple show query...")
    spark.read.parquet("/tmp/x").show()

    println("Running simple UDF query...")

    // Adding external library to project
    spark.sparkContext.addJar("./target/scala-2.11/hello-world_2.11-1.0.jar")
    spark.udf.register("f", (x: Int) => x + 1)
    spark.range(10).selectExpr("f(id)").show()

    println("Running custom objects query...")
    val objs = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Foo("bye"), Foo("hi"))).collect()
    println(objs.toSeq)
  }
}
```

It's also worth noting that the DBR version running on the cluster and the DB Connect version running on your local machine need to be the same.

Comment: `sc.addJar` doesn't work (same error), I have the same version (already mentioned that above), and I don't see where in your code you use functions from `hello-world`.